# Why does route rule not work when I set mark after the net packet go through the 'forward chain' of iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, route

I want to that all the packets through 'farword chain' redirect to local loopback, so that I can proxy this traffic. I set the route rules of iproute2 (all the packet with mark 1 is routed to local loopback),and then set mark 1 for packet in FORWARD chain of iptables. The content is as follows:

PS: When I set mark 1 for packet in PREROUTING chain of iptables. this route rule works ok. but it not work in FORWARD chain of iptables. I don't know the reason.

```
// OS System: 

# iptables -V
iptables v1.4.21

# uname -a
Linux centos7 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 19 16:18:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

//set mark 1 route rule

# ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
# ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100

# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup 100
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip route list table 100
local default dev lo scope host


// set mark 1 in FORWARD chain

# iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 169.254.2.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 1

# iptables -nL -t mangle
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
UTPROXY    all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
LOG        tcp  --  192.168.11.1         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "pre:"

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        tcp  --  192.168.11.1         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "input:"

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MARK       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            169.254.2.0/24       MARK set 0x1
LOG        tcp  --  192.168.11.1         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "forward:"

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.11.1         tcp spt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "output:"

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.11.1         tcp spt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "post:"
LOG        tcp  --  192.168.11.1         0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:!22 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "post:"

Chain UTPROXY (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
TPROXY     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            169.254.2.0/24       TPROXY redirect 0.0.0.0:2001 mark 0x1/0x1
```

I do it based on this document.

[This is the iptables work proccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SMmZ.png)

It does not work ok. The logs is as follows:

[This is the iptables log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrO1g.png)

Comment: the reroute check / 2nd routing decision is the function ip_route_me_harder() . it's called by ipt_mangle_out() which only exists from local path (not forward path): https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.7/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_mangle.c#L77 . This is to tell the 2nd reroute check never happens in forward path: schematics are wrong (this one too is wrong: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right.

Comment: @A.B Wtf mate, you're right. Damn Wikipedia, fix your diagrams!